# Run factory function on import in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

It's a common pattern in Node to run a function on import, e.g. `require("debug")("debug:namespace")`. Is there a way to do that in TS? Or is there an elegant replacement?

In the `debug` example I'm importing the package like so: `import * as debugInitalizer from "debug"` and then later declaring `const debug = debugInitializer("debug:namespace")` but that is pretty verbose. Is there a more elegant TypeScript way or a way to emulate the above pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) has strict syntax that lets it be statically analyzed, it cannot contain expressions.

Since `debug` is CommonJS module that exports a function and not an object, it requires special treatment when being imported.

As the snippet in the question suggests, the established way to call CommonJS export in TypeScript 2.x is:

```
import * as debugFactory from "debug";
const debug = debugFactory("debug:namespace");
```

It is readable and type-safe alternative to raw `require` call that doesn't cause problems in general; ES modules may get other benefits from `import`, but tree shaking is not applicable here.

Another way to write this that doesn't contradict ES module specification and tends to be future-proof is TypeScript-specific `import..require` syntax:

```
import debugFactory = require("debug");
const debug = debugFactory("debug:namespace");
```

In TypeScript 2.7 and higher, it's possible to use `esModuleInterop` compiler option that adds synthetic `default` export to CommonJS modules (which `debug` is) and changes import syntax to:

```
import debugFactory from "debug";
const debug = debugFactory("debug:namespace");
```

**The above-mentioned ways don't allow for one-liner that treats an import as expression and chains it with function call.**

[Dynamic imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html) can involve expressions, but since they are promise-based, this will be:

```
// inside async function
const debug = (await import("debug"))("debug:namespace");
```

Comment: Except that the import you've shown is used in an invalid manner. The only reason that works is because of sloppy transportation that is neither guaranteed going forward nor maintainable when someone else uses the source code and targets a different module format. Please fix this I know you know better

Comment: To be crystal clear if you write `import * as debugFactory`, and it is absolutely invalid to call `debugFactory`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad This is how CJS modules are handled in TS (may be different in Babel where CJS exports can be shimmed with `default`). The answer doesn't address ES modules in general (neither does the question), where * cannot be a function. The case is very specific, `debug` is commonly used NPM CJS package (primarily Node), its export is a function. If * wasn't a function, `require("debug")(...)` wouldn't work too, right? If you have legit information that is applicable to current case and contradicts the answer, please, consider providing it.

Comment: No, first of all your information out of date, as TypeScript now supports default import interop. Secondly, require would work and for common JS AMD or UMD it is the correct syntax

Comment: esModuleInterop option isn't default compiler behaviour and it's very unlikely it will become one because this will break too many things in existing code, I personally don't use it for this reason. This doesn't make the answer incorrect as you stated above, and the downvote is unjustified. I updated the post for completeness.

Comment: `import = ...require` would be the conservative approach

Comment: I do feel that downvote was justified. I'm tired of seeing people do it wrong, writing incompatible code for no reason. I know you're knowledgeable about this and that you should promote good practices as you otherwise do.

Comment: This subject is opinionated to some degree, and I see nothing wrong in * imports from CJS modules; they work as expected, they are supported and have been conventionally used in TS development for long time. `import = require()` certainly cannot be recommended here. It's weird legacy extension over JS, it may be looser than ES6 import, and most importantly, it can cause *Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules*, so it's of no use in modern TS. If you have other recommendations on improving the answer, I'd appreciate them.

Comment: For one thing, while `import...require` _was_ considered legacy for a time, it is no longer. Daniel Rossenwasser and other TypeScript designers have recommended it. There's are many discussion which I will dig up and link. It is absolutely the most reliable way when using command JS, AMD or UMD modules. In fact, when importing a UMD style declaration, and targeting one of those formats (when synthetic defaults are not enabled) the TypeScript language service will automatically generate such an import in quick fixes. I implemented that behavior, and it was discussed and approved.

Comment: If you're targeting es2015 modules. You must use the synthetic default, however you get it, whether via Rollup, Webpack, SystemJS, Babel, or TS because using the star import not only violates the es2015 module target, which will cause **failure** on the recent versions of Node.js and also in Rollup, but also because TypeScript plans to make it an error ultimately. It violates the specification. And if you're importing from a CommonJS module, in a node targeting ES Modules, `* as` violates the node interop spec, which mandates that `module.exports` may only be provided via synthetic default.

Comment: It's a hairy subject, but the namespaces import mapping to `module.exports`  should be considered legacy typescript specific and non-standard if anything is

Comment: Here is a link to the pivotal github issue there's a lot of interesting discussion. Both about practicality, culture, documentation, and legacy of the syntax https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16093 By the way, I appreciate the cordial discussion we've had here

Comment: Thanks for the link. Instantly stumbled upon https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11340 . It seems there's still no consensus on import-require deprecation state. The post proves the point about * import, it has been widely used by the community. 'resolves to non-module entity' problem that's mentioned there could be an argument against *, but I never encountered it myself. Are you aware of the conditions under which it can appear? IME, import-require had inferior support in IDEs, I believe I had problems with it in webstorm and possibly elsewhere, while ES import was fully supported

Comment: Jetbrains has their own language service for webstorm, which by the way can be disabled for the TS language language service which has long had full support for `import...require`, especially as it was the initial syntax. `* as ns` imports are safe to use if you are not calling `ns` but I would advise against using them unless you are importing from an ES Module (e.g. those that are shipped as part of Angular's distribution in several subdirectories). I recommend the require syntax when targeting formats where it's available because of its reliability. Using the new interop option is also good

Comment: It's also worth noting that the typescript team massively refactored DefinitelyTyped, removing the star imports all over the place a few months ago. In the process they introduced a number of require style imports very deliberately. They've now started setting the esm interop flag in those types packages

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the use of import-require by the team. This doesn't affect my own projects because I have zero problems with * and most times cannot use esModuleInterop but possibly will affect my OS habits.

Comment: I still don't recommend it because your code is now dependent on being transpiled in a legacy way, but thanks for clarifying your answer. Downvote removed

Comment: Since it wasn't a focus of the question, it's fair to let the readers decide what's good for them.

Comment: I'm sure anyone reading these comments can get to the bottom out if they care to. Frankly I would have approached the entire situation differently now that I think about it. I would have declared an overload of require that had the proper type but that could be imported without using the ts import= syntax