# How to write require that takes an argument in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to import a module that takes an argument in Typescript.
I have this written in javascript:

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true}); // JS
```

How can I write the same expression in Typescript?

Comment: Is required a function that you have created or imported somewhere?

Comment: no, required is a JS namespace used to import another module (file) into the intended module.

Comment: I believe you mean `require()` and not `required()` with a 'd'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no way to do this with a single import statement.

#### What is that unusual `require` statement doing?

This can be better understood if you decompose the `require` statement.

When you write `const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});`, what you are actually doing is as follows:

```
const corsPackage = require('cors');
const cors = corsPackage({origin: true});
```

Notice that you're simply importing the package, then initializing it.

---

### Solution

The proper way to rewrite this in ES6 / TypeScript is as follows:

First import the desired package:

```
import cors from 'cors';
```

Now you can either initialize `cors` inline, or assign it to a variable:

```
// Assigning the initialized `cors` package to a variable
const allowCors = cors({origin: true});

// OR, initialize it as the point of usage. For example, with express:
router.use(cors(options));
```

---

#### Why was this so difficult to find the answer for?

The reason you're not seeing this method importing the `cors` package in its documentation using the ES6 `import` statement is because the package is meant to be used with Node on the backend; and not in the browser.

Until Node v10.0 LTS is released, you will need to use the `--experimental-modules` flag to use this feature.

---

> Your question is referring to using the ES6 `import` statement; which is not TypeScript specfic, but instead is a feature you inherit because of TypeScripts transpilation to browser-compatible code.

Comment: I change import cors from 'cors'; 
to 
 import * as cors from 'cors';

Comment: @NasserAlghamid See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722246/3731501 for the explanation of different import flavours.