# Jest: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Im trying to test my React class, that has `import dotnetify from "dotnetify";` import. That works fine, but Jest says, that dotnetify is undefined. If i change to `const dotnetify = require("dotnetify");`, Jest passes test, but this is silly workaround. How to explain Jest, that dotnetify is not undefined?

Than you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be 'explained' to Jest, it's really undefined.

There are several ways to handle CommonJS modules in TypeScript. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722246/3731501), there will be default import in CommonJS packge only if synthetic imports were enabled with `esModuleInterop` (`allowSyntheticDefaultImports`) compiler option.

Otherwise it should be done like:

```
import * as dotnetify from "dotnetify";
```

Or with TypeScript-specific syntax:

```
import dotnetify = require("dotnetify")
```

Comment: import * as dotnetify from "dotnetify" is best approach for me. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The other two are considered more future-proof, but I guess it's not a big deal in this particular case.

Comment: What else can I try? I have both esModuleInterop and allowSyntheticDefaultImports enabled and I am getting error from typescript module not CommonJS. My export is really simple as `export let config: AppConfig;` then later on `config = {...}` and et the end of file `export default config;`. Then import in another file `import config from '@/services/config.service';` fails in jest, works in app like a charm. `const config = require('@/services/config.service');` fixes issue but I dont like to have require in my modern 2020 typescript project :D

Comment: @Luckylooke What exactly is the error? If you tried `import config from '@/services/config.service'`, did you try to replace default import with `* as config` instead, as the answer suggests? `import..require` is TS-specific syntax that provides type safety for `require`. You will need `require` in Jest any way for module mocking.

Comment: @Luckylooke The question and the answer are specific to third-party *CommonJS* Node packages, e.g. dotnetify. That you have a problem with your own *ES modules* means that Jest+Babel+TS setup went wrong at some point. I'd suggest to ask a new question that shows your setup and explains the problem.

Comment: Exact error was "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apiUrl' of undefined", I did tried '* as config' but didn't help, BUT now I have find out why. Now I just don't know why it was working in app. My problem was that I have exported uninitialised constant `export let config: AppConfig;` and then later on initialise it `config = {...}` there for in time of export it was undefined. But it is mystery to me why it works in app without error, maybe it executes code and then resolve exports? ‍♂️ and jest do opposite? Why it is different? Isn't same ts compiler used? At least issue is solved for me 

Comment: I will create QA with my findings. Thanks for your will to help and kindness 

Comment: @Luckylooke *export let config: AppConfig; and then later on initialise it config = {...}* - this makes use of the semantics of ES modules that keep their exports updated, so it will break if modules don't behave like ES modules. No, setups are different, in production it's likely Webpack+TypeScript where Webpack does the job on module interoperation and bundles them, and in Jest it's TS+probably Babel with unbundled CommonJS modules because Jest runs in Node. It's ts-jest that is usually responsible in Jest setups to make TS work like it's expected in tests.

Comment: For anyone reading this with same error but for an HTML template property giving problems - I had to add a `?` in my html template for Jest to play nice and not treat it undefined.