# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined using jest

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using ***jest*** framework to unit-test my ***Angular*** application. I'm having trouble in *test.ts* file with the *zone.js* I think.

I'm getting the error stack trace

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

      3 | import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
      4 | import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
    > 5 | import {
        | ^
      6 |   BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      7 |   platformBrowserDynamicTesting
      8 | } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

      at __extends (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:394:73)
      at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:530:9
      at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:619:7
      at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:620:3
      at Object.<anonymous>.NEWLINE (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:9:65)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:12:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/test.ts:5:1
```

I'm looking for a way to fix this issue with the minimum changes in code.

I have already tried to adapt to the solutions given in
https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n/issues/233
and
[Jest: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427196/jest-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined) without any luck.

Also, I have tried the docs, but it does not specify anything related to this or I have missed it.

This is my *test.ts* file.

```js
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

I have used the **`compilerOptions`**,

```js
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "es2015",
```

As I have said, I'm looking for a way to fix this with minimum code change. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have completely migrated to Jest, you can just delete test.ts as it's not required anymore since you are not using Jasmine and Karma anymore. You can read [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/integrate-jest-into-an-angular-application-and-library-163b01d977ce).

Also, make sure to remove its reference from tsconfig.spec.ts.

If for some reason, you need to keep it, you can ignore test.ts files in Jest configuration, as by default jest will test all files ending with spec.ts/js and test.ts/js.

```
**Default configuration:** 
testMatch: [ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ]

**Change to:**
testMatch: [ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.spec).[jt]s?(x)" ]
```

You can read more about configuring Jest [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried it before also. Then it produced the following error.
`TypeScript diagnostics (customize using '[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics' option):
    error TS6053: File '.../Sample-Login-App_jest/src/test.ts' not found.`
After some tinkering, I saw that the ***tsconfig.spec.ts*** file includes ***test.ts*** file in its *files* array. After I removed it, tests were working fine. Thanks

Comment: Great, I'll update the answer with that. Might help someone else. :)