# Jest: TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am creating new QA issue to share my findings as I have got same error as discussed already in SO but my problem was elsewhere. Reference: [Jest: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427196/jest-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined#comment111701302_50427444)

I was getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apiUrl' of undefined". I could not find out why. I had already set esModuleInterop and allowSyntheticDefaultImports tsconfig.json so I thought all export types are supported.

Error occurs in service consumer

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import config from '@/services/config.service';

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: config.apiUrl || undefined,
                  ^^^^^^
  ...
});
```

where config services exported const config and even as default export too

```
export let config: AppConfig;

...

config = {...}

...

export default config;
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["node", "webpack-env", "jest", "googlemaps"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/types/**/*",
    "src/WS_UIkit/src/types/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  // testMatch: ['**/*.spec.[jt]s?(x)],'
  testMatch: ['**/*.spec.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // FIXES Could not locate module @/types mapped as: .../cart/src/types.
    '^@/types$': '<rootDir>/src/types/index.d',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(quasar|quasar/*))'],
};
```

my babel config

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/app'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'transform-imports',
      {
        quasar: {
          transform: 'quasar/dist/babel-transforms/imports.js',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: Consider providing full TS and Jest configurations, the problem is specific to them.

Comment: Is there Babel config too? Please, provide it. Did you try to switch to `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript`?

Comment: same result with `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript` :)

Comment: At this point this is specific to your Vue setup rather than Jest+TS in general. I'm not totally sure why it's working at this point then. I'd expect `"module": "esnext"` to not work with `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript` alone, this would result in untransformed `import` and syntax error. Make sure tsconfig is really picked up by Jest by doing syntax mistake there. If it still works, that's the problem. Otherwise fork a separate tsconfig.test.json, change it to `"module": "commonjs"` and provide it to Jest.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about this Vue Jest preset, but I guess the config should become something like `module.exports = require('deepmerge')(require('@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript'), { globals: {'ts-jest': { tsConfig: 'tsconfig.test.json' } } })`. If it works, also make sure that tsconfig.test.json is picked up, too.

Comment: I do not have extra tsconfig for tests 'tsconfig.test.json', should I have?

Comment: Yes, you usually should, I end up with a one in all projects. Extend it from prod config with `extends`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I have exported uninitialised constant export `let config: AppConfig;` and then, later on, initialised it `config = {...}` therefore in time of export it is `undefined`. But it is a mystery to me why it works in app without error, maybe it executes code and then resolves exports? And jest does the opposite? Why it is different? Isn't the same ts compiler used? At least the issue is solved for me.

Comment: ESModule imports are what's called "live bindings", when you export a const (or a variable) and then modify it - it will change in all files that `import` it - this is different scoping than elsewhere in JS and it enables circular references.